# Passing data from partial view through view into controller in MVC Razor Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If anyone could helo with explanation or simply can or can't do...

I have a view with a couple partial views, i every partial i put some data, alter this in main view i click submit button,

Now is my question how can i gather data from this partial views into my controller action (it is create action)

For more details in every partial view i have some jQuery action to handle that data so perfect example will be example of passing data through path like this:

**jQuery -> partialView-> view -> controller**

is there a way of collecting that data in ViewBag or something similar ?

//==================================

There comes bigger explanation

I have a application that have a configuration with model:

```
    Configuration Model
    {
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reduction> Reductions { get; set; }
    public int AstroId { get; set; }
    public int DarkId { get; set; }
    public int TermoId { get; set; } 
    }
```

so when a open a create configuration i have a page with field for name of configuration and a dropdownlist where i can choose collection of elements that builds configuration (Astro, Dark, Termo) when i choose for example Astro under first Dropdownlist appears second dropdownlist that contains all Astroes available to choose - that second dropdowlist is partial view. When i choose element in second dropdownlist i add that element to an array in jQuery and display value in list on create main view.

There is code from partial view:

```
 @using SmartLightAPI.lampsCF
 @{
LampsContext dbContext = new LampsContext();
}
<script>
function wybierzClick() {
    if ($('#astroes :selected').text() != "---WYBIERZ---") {
      var Id = $('#astroes').val();
      var Txt = $('#astroes :selected').text();
      $('#astroList').text(Txt);
}};
</script>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("wybierz Astro", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("astroes", new SelectList(dbContext.Astros, "AstroID", "Name"), "---   W WYBIERZ---", new { @class = "form-control" }) <a href="#" onclick="wybierzClick()">Wybierz</a>
    @Html.ActionLink("Dodaj astro", "Create", "Astroes")
</div>
</div>
```

as i choose it i want to pass to the controller vale of "astroIdArray" a situation is similar for other elements i guess that i do not have to post code from main view but as keeping it as clear as possible i using             @Html.Partial("ReductionPartialViewResult") for including partial views on page.

Comment: Of course you can. You render a view based on a model, render a form and controls using html helpers and submit the form back to a method that accepts the model as a parameter. If something is not working, post the code and explain the problem.

Comment: If you are submitting a form and partial views contain form inputs, then they would be submitted to the controller.

Comment: i will edit firts post and add to it big explanation and code but it take me some time to make it all clear.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. What is `Configuration Model`? Do you mean `public class Configuration`? Your partial has no relationship to your model and why are you using partial anyway? What is it that you actually want to post back to your controller?

Comment: yes pubic class Configuration,
i use partial view for making all more user-friendly, yes there is no relation of partial to configuration cause in partials contains elements which can be choose to add to configuration not element that is already a part of configuration. 
in this example i want to post a value of "Id" from jQuery

i change code cause i actually need only one AstroId so array is no longer neccesary